# Stop one children component re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I use react-card-flip to create an app. Children component gets props from parents'. How to prevent props change(re-render) when particular one flip back? The structure is like this:

<YOUR_FRONT_CCOMPONENT>
This is the front of the card.
Click to flip
</YOUR_FRONT_CCOMPONENT>

```
    <YOUR_BACK_COMPONENT>
      This is the back of the card.
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
    </YOUR_BACK_COMPONENT>
  </ReactCardFlip>
```

Answer (score 0):

to prevent rerendering you can use `React.memo()`

```
const YOUR_BACK_COMPONENT = React.memo((props) => {

   return ....
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {

  //do stuff to compare. return true to re-render and vice versa
} )
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: I use hooks for the app. can I use usememo instead of memo? what's the difference?

Comment: useMemo only memorises the value/variable/state to prevent recalculating of expensive operations, but does not stop rerendering. React.memo is a HOC

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`React.PureComponent`** or **`React.memo()`**.

First things first: **`React.memo()` does the same as `PureComponent` but it does not check for changes in `state`, only in `props`.**

**Find more info **here**:**
https://medium.com/takeaway-tech/a-deep-dive-into-pure-component-and-react-memo-and-why-do-we-need-them-ae99dce6a33c